# XSl parameter current display name in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, xslt

I'm using a search core results and using xsl to filter the results based on the Author in a discussion list. LOGON_USER as parameter, it works fine when the Author displays the login. But if the Author displays the display name it does not mach the LOGON_USER.

Is there a way of setting a xsl parameter to point to the current user display name or last name and first name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UserLookup` function of `ddwrt` namespace in XSLT to return user login based on display name, check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143(v=office.11).aspx#officesharepointddwrt_userlookup